# How do you setup a caching proxy on OSX?

Tags: squid, caching-proxy

When doing web development there are times external resources are referenced in a web page (e.g. google fonts). I would like to cache some of these calls on my Macbook but not cache the code Im working on.

The goal being speed of development and a workaround when working on slow networks (e.g. 3G using a hotspot).

I came across Squid proxy but have not been able to configure it at all. Im open to other suggestions to achieve this goal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using SquidMan : http://squidman.net
It come with a nice user interface.